# Calculate an area of a manifold

Tags: integration, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The question is to calculate the area of this manifold:

$\sum=\left\{ x^{2}+y^{2}=2az\right\} \cap\left\{ \left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}<2a^{2}xy\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I didnt managed to think of parameterization to help me. I also tried to find an open set that its boundary is $\sum$ and then use the divergence theorem but I didn't find such open set.

Thank you very much!

Peleg

Edit:

After Math Lover's comment, I try to solve this integral in with this parameterization:
$\psi\left(r,\theta\right)=\left(rcos\theta,rsin\theta,\frac{r^{2}}{2a}\right)$ (as Math Lover recommend)
to find the boundaries:
$r^{4}<2a^{2}r^{2}cos\theta sin\theta$ so $0<r<\sqrt[]{2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}$

and also I want that:

$cos\theta sin\theta>0$, so: $\theta=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cup\left(\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$
$\intop_{\sum}1=\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\intop_{0}^{\sqrt[]{2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}}\sqrt{\Gamma\left(\psi_{r},\psi_{\theta}\right)}drd\theta+\intop_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\intop_{0}^{\sqrt[]{2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}}\sqrt{\Gamma\left(\psi_{r},\psi_{\theta}\right)}drd\theta$
$\psi_{r}=\left(cos\theta,sin\theta,\frac{r}{a}\right),\,\psi_{\theta}=\left(-rsin\theta,rcos\theta,0\right),\left\langle \psi_{r},\psi_{r}\right\rangle =1+\frac{r^{2}}{a^{2}},\left\langle \psi_{\theta},\psi_{\theta}\right\rangle =r^{2},
\left\langle \psi_{r},\psi_{\theta}\right\rangle =-rcos\theta sin\theta+rsin\theta cos\theta=0$
$\Gamma\left(\psi_{r},\psi_{\theta}\right)=r^{2}\left(1+\frac{r^{2}}{a^{2}}\right).$
$\intop_{0}^{\sqrt{2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}}\sqrt{\Gamma\left(\psi_{r},\psi_{\theta}\right)}dr=\intop_{0}^{\sqrt{2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}}r\sqrt{1+\frac{r^{2}}{a^{2}}}dr=\frac{a^{2}}{2}\intop_{0}^{\sqrt[]{2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}}\sqrt{1+\frac{r^{2}}{a^{2}}}\cdot\frac{2r}{a^{2}}\cdot dr=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
u=1+\frac{r^{2}}{a^{2}} & du=\frac{2r}{a^{2}}du\\
\\
\end{array}\right]=\frac{a^{2}}{2}\intop_{1}^{1+2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}u^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot du\\=\frac{a^{2}}{2}\frac{u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}|_{1}^{1+2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta}=\frac{a^{2}}{3}\cdot\left(\left(1+2a^{2}cos\theta sin\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-1\right)=\frac{a^{2}}{3}\cdot\left(\left(1+a^{2}sin2\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-1\right)$
but then I had problem with this integral:
$\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a^{2}}{3}\cdot\left(\left(1+a^{2}sin2\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-1\right)d\theta=\frac{a^{2}}{3}\left(\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1+a^{2}sin2\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1\right)$

Maybe I did something wrong?
Thank you very much

Comment: The repeated appearance of $x^2+y^2$ makes me think cylindrical coordinates might be useful.

Comment: something like that: $r\left(\theta,h\right)=\left(\sqrt{2ah}cos\theta,\sqrt{2ah}sin\theta,h\right)$ ?

Comment: How do you parametrize a paraboloid surface? Alternatively why parametrize at all? Simply use surface area formula given you already know $z = f(x,y)$

Comment: Parametrize a paraboloid is like this: $r\left(u,v\right)=\left(\sqrt{2a}u,\sqrt{2a}v,u^{2}+v^{2}\right)$?  By surface area formula do you mean co-area formula? Unfortunately, I still can't see the solution. I think my main issue is with $\left\{ \left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}<2a^{2}xy\right\} $. Thank you very much

Comment: use polar coordinates. parametrize as $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, \frac{r^2}{2a})$. Use the other equation to find bounds of $r, \theta$ for integral.

Comment: In the future, try to use "\cos\theta" ($\cos\theta$) instead of "cos\theta" ($cos\theta$) to make it easier to read.

Comment: Ok I will do it! Thank you for letting me know!